# instead of uploading doc i need to choose only path in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have an application which needs the full path of the file when clicking on choose file button. Now I want to get the full path of that file. For e.g. D:\MyNodeApp\project\text.doc

How do I get the file location in node.js?

Comment: Why the <sql> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not possible because of security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you want client file location you can get this in client side using javascript

```
document.getElementById("file-upload").onchange = function(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.srcElement.files[0]);
    var me = this;
    reader.onload = function () {
      console.log(reader)
    }
```

Comment: no actually what I want whenever I am going to click on choose file button that time I want a path of that file instead of the only name.